# ListPicker SelectionChanged Property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am attempting to choose a specific item upon the `SelectionChanged` event of the `ListPicker` for WP8.I have two list pickers, I want to implement them such that when I select a particular item it changes the items on the other `ListPicker`. Any ideas how I could achieve this thanks in advance?

Comment: what you have done to acheive this ?

Comment: You could subscribe to the "SelectionChanged" event on the first list picker, then change the Items in the second list picker after that. There should good code examples if you search online.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay within the mvvm model, it might not be a bad idea to implement a attached property to invoke a command when the selection changes have a look at this post which shows an implementation:

[ListBox SelectionChanged not getting called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21748150/listbox-selectionchanged-not-getting-called/21748415#21748415)